New Attributes Added to Data Cloud Activation Not Reflected in Data Extension
I recently added new attributes to an existing and active Data Cloud activation in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. However, the corresponding Data Extension in SFMC didn’t update to include the new fields.
Is this expected behavior? Does adding attributes to an active activation not update the DE structure? If so, is creating a new activation the only solution?
Any advice on handling this would be appreciated.
